# Moving to specific sheet

Tags: excel

I need to make a box where you type the number of the sheet you just want to go and it takes you there. I wanted to the a button, but it does not make much sense since I have about 60 sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Run this small macro:

```
Sub GoThere()
Dim N As Long
   On Error Resume Next
      N = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter sheet number", Type:=1)
      Sheets(N).Select
   On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the macro, but it is not working for me. I have 60 sheets but their names are not like 1-60 but 4-28, 38-46 and so on. (numbers of checkout in a hypermarket). so when i type the number (NAME) of the sheet nothing happens. Forgive me for i am noob :D thanks

Comment: You must type a genuine **number** like **1,2,3,4...** , not the **name** of the sheet.